# Write to docx Apache POI

Tags: java, xml, apache-poi, docx

I try to write parsed text from xml to docx file with apache poi XWPFDocument, but at tmpParagraph.createRun() method it throws NPE, any advise?

```
public  void dothis() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("P.xml"));
    XWPFDocument document1 = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document1.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun tmpRun = (XWPFRun) tmpParagraph.createRun();
    document1.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("post.docx")));
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    // Get the DOM Builder
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse("P.xml");
    List<Elementt> empList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Complete Stacktrace please...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at gui.copy.Main.dothis(Main.java:98)
 at gui.copy.Main.main(Main.java:57

Comment: Is `tmpParagraph` null? If so, why? (The `createParagraph` docs ought to say…)